# python does not write csv file

Tags: python, csv

So, I am trying to copy all of the rows from one CSV file to the other. I saw similar questions, but they are done in a different manner. I have been following a youtube tutorial, but the guy does it and it works just fine. It creates the new file "new_names.csv" but it is empty.

```
with open('csv_for_python.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)  

with open('new_names.csv', 'w') as new_file:  
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter='-')

    for line in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: You do know the indentation of your second line is off? Please check the rest as well.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the second `with` block. Once the first context manager (the first `with` block ends the file is closed. So there is nothing to read.

Comment: Well, actually it was nested in the code, it just wasn't made up correctly in the text box. Anyway i fixed the problem now. It turned out that is was an indentation problem indeed. Lesson learnt "use spaces not tabs". Thanks for the help!